# Problem when i try to publish my ASP.NET CORE web app in azure - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, identity

I am new in asp.net core and azure.
I have small web app on asp.net core mvc, and I want to publish this project to azure. Locally the project work fine, but when I try to build the project through the console on azure, this error appears -

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.1.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at
>   program.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

When i try to open across his link I see this: 
An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Core 4.6.27129.04 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.1.1-rtm-30846    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?

And my question is: What I need to do, to fix this error ?

Comment: What does your `Startup` class look like?

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/vU8fwPZG) Here can see all code from StartUp class.

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I didn't change anything on my end. I just checked the site randomly and then I got this error as well. I also get HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when I try to hit the site. I also don't know why it's looking for Version 2.1.6.0 of that. The only version I'm referencing of that library is 2.2.0 even after doing a text string search via Notepad++. What's going on...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a very similar error on my core 2.1 site published as an Azure App Service:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.1.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

It was running perfectly until it suddenly stopped working. I honestly don't know why the issue started but in the mean time I solved it by changing the "Deployment Mode" to "Self-Contained" on the publish profile settings.

To get there just right click your website, click on publish, select your profile and click on Configure. Then click on Settings and change the "Deployment Mode". That will  add all the ddl's locally and get your site working again.

[Visual Studio publish profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACbM0.png)

Comment: I appreciate the help. 
I changed it and it does not work yet. I can't find solution for my problem in internet.

Comment: I appreciate the help. 
I changed it and it does not work yet. I can't find solution for my problem in internet. This is my azure portatl - pipeline - build https://imgur.com/a/uwLuY6i, everythink is ok, the app build correct but when open in browser i see : This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: @Hemanth Bidare, not yet. Do you have any ideas, how can i solve the problem?

Comment: I resolved it by mentioning the versions in my package file.